# Update existing list values with values from another query

Tags: linq

I have a linq statement which calls a stored proc and returns a list of items and descriptions.

Like so;

`var q = from i in doh.usp_Report_PLC()
                        where i.QTYGood == 0
                        orderby i.PartNumber
                        select new Parts() { PartNumber = i.PartNumber, Description = i.Descritpion.TrimEnd() };`

I then have another SQL statement which returns the quantities on order and delivery date for each of those items. The Parts class has two other properties to store these. How do I update the existing Parts list with the other two values so that there is one Parts list with all four values?

**UPDATE**

The following code now brings out results.

```
                var a = from a1 in db.usp_Optos_DaysOnHand_Report_PLC()
                    where a1.QTYGood == 0
                    orderby a1.PartNumber
                    select new Parts() { PartNumber = a1.PartNumber, Description = a1.Descritpion.TrimEnd() };

            var b = from b1 in db.POP10110s
                    join b2 in db.IV00101s on b1.ITEMNMBR equals b2.ITEMNMBR
                    //from b3 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where b1.POLNESTA == 2 && b1.QTYCANCE == 0
                    group b1 by new { itemNumber = b2.ITMGEDSC } into g
                    select new Parts() { PartNumber = g.Key.itemNumber.TrimEnd(), QtyOnOrder = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.QTYORDER)), DeliveryDue = g.Max(x => x.REQDATE).ToShortDateString() };

            var joinedList = a.Join(b,
                    usp => usp.PartNumber,
                    oss => oss.PartNumber,
                    (usp, oss) =>
                         new Parts
                         {
                             PartNumber = usp.PartNumber,
                             Description = usp.Description,
                             QtyOnOrder = oss.QtyOnOrder,
                             DeliveryDue = oss.DeliveryDue
                         });

            return joinedList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "other SQL statement" returns `PartNumber`, `Quantity` and `DeliveryDate`, you can join the lists into one:

```
var joinedList = q.Join(OtherSQLStatement(), 
                        usp => usp.PartNumber,
                        oss => oss.PartNumber,
                        (usp, oss) => 
                             new Parts
                                    {
                                        PartNumber = usp.PartNumber,
                                        Description = usp.Description,
                                        Quantity = oss.Quantity,
                                        DeliveryDate = oss.DeliveryDate
                                    }).ToList();
```

You can actually combine the queries and do this in one join and projection:

```
var joinedList = doh.usp_Report_PLC().
                     Where(i => i.QTYGood == 0).
                     OrderBy(i => i.PartNumber).
                     Join(OtherSQLStatement(), 
                          i => i.PartNumber,
                          o => o.PartNumber,
                          (i, o) => 
                               new Parts
                                    {
                                        PartNumber = i.PartNumber,
                                        Description = i.Description,
                                        Quantity = o.Quantity,
                                        DeliveryDate = o.DeliveryDate
                                    }).ToList();
```

And again: I assume you have `PartNumber` in both returned collections to identify which item belongs to which.

**Edit**

In this case the LINQ Query syntax would probably be more readable:

```
var joinedList = from aElem in a
                 join bElem in b
                 on aElem.PartNumber equals bElem.PartNumber into joinedAB
                 from abElem in joinedAB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new Part
                            {
                                PartNumber = aElem.PartNumber,
                                Description = aElem.Description,
                                DeliveryDue = abElem == null ? null : abElem.DeliveryDue,
                                QtyOnOrder = abElem == null ? null : abElem.QtyOnOrder
                            };
```

Your `DeliveryDue` and `QtyOnOrder` are probably nullable. If not, replace the nulls by your default values. E.g. if you don't have the element in `b` and want `QtyOnOrder` to be `0` in the resulting list, change the line to

```
QtyOnOrder = abElem == null ? 0 : abElem.QtyOnOrder
```

Comment: Do I replace OtherSQLStatement() with the actual Linq query or do I put the Linq query in another function called OtherSQLStatement() and then return the result from that?

Comment: Other Linq query;
var j = from a in doh.POP10110s
where a.ITEMNMBR.StartsWith("PARTNUMBER") && a.POLNESTA == 2 && a.QTYCANCE == 0
group a by new { itemNumber = a.ITEMNMBR } into g
select new Parts() { PartNumber = g.Key.itemNumber, QtyOnOrder = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.QTYORDER)), OrderExpected = g.Max(x => x.REQDATE) };

Comment: To check that it works, you can first join your `q` and `j`. Replace `OtherSQLQuery()` by `j` in the first (topmost) solution. If it does work as expected, I will edit my answer and include a large query that would contain everything.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my original post but unfortunately the code above doesn't return any results.

Comment: I have the same problem as the post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819868/linq-merge-queries. I tried Thomas Levesque solution but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you check the individual lists and see if they contain the expected results? Just run `q.ToList();` and `j.ToList()` and see what the lists contain.

Comment: My laptop is about to die so I'll have a look again in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: Each Linq query (q and j) gives the expected output so it must be a problem with the join.

Comment: Does the join work correctly if you convert `q` and `j` to lists first and try to join the lists?

Comment: I mean if you do `var joinedList = q.ToList().Join(j.ToList(), ...`?

Comment: That's actually good news. That means that the partnumbers don't match in the lists. Can you post at least part of the data in those lists?

Comment: Looking at the data, it does look like the PartNumbers are different. I'll see if I can figure out why. Thanks

Comment: Updated the code above which now outputs results, however it doesn't output any items where an item in a doesn't exist in b. (e.g. a contains 6 items, the output contains 5). The output should always contain all the items in a regardless of the values in b.